# How to animate a <tr> opening/closing up and down with automatic property calculation

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

I have a table row that is not visible until you click a "view details" button on the row above it. Currently I am using *ngIf to display the second row and changing a boolean property of the bound object when the "View details" button is clicked. I have read through the animations page on the angular2 documentation and tried to implement a "collapse/uncollapse" animation so that when the 2nd table row becomes visible it animates from 0px height -> the height of the row fully expanded (*px).

The closest example I saw to what I want to do was this animation which removed the hero from however tall it was (*px) to 0px and it collapsed/slid upwards smoothly.

```
animations: [
 trigger('shrinkOut', [
  state('in', style({height: '*'})),
  transition('* => void', [
    style({height: '*'}),
    animate(250, style({height: 0}))
  ])
 ])
]
```

I can't get this to work for my situation described above. I tried it in combination with *ngIf and that didn't work. (The row just instantly opens/closes like it was before adding the animation.) I tried getting rid of *ngIf and binding to the [hidden] property with no success. I also tried removing *ngIf and [hidden] and just having the animation but that didn't work either (the row just stayed open and never closed.)

My 2nd table row HTML looks like:

```
<tr [@visibilityChanged]="visibility">
      <td  colspan="8" class="details-row">
          ...
      </td>
</tr>
```

My animation looks like:

```
trigger('visibilityChanged', [
  state('hidden', style({height: '*'})),
  transition('* => void', [
    style({height: '*'}),
    animate(1000, style({height: 0}))
  ])
])
```

and the visibility variable is a string in the component which changes from "hidden" to "shown" and vice versa when the view details button is clicked.

Is what I am trying to accomplish possible with angular 2 animations?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for a good while myself. Then I realized, we need to animate the cell  height, not the row height. It is the text in each table cell that is causing your row to remain at its fixed height, and not respect the row height animation, therefore, the row never collapses, it just "snaps" into view.

So add your trigger bindings to each td, as follows: (only two cells shown to save space)

```
<tr>
<td class="col3Destination" [@rowVisibleState]="row.isVisible">{{row.version}} 
/td>
<td class="col4Destination" [@rowVisibleState]="row.isVisible">{{row.dataType}}</td>
</tr>
```

And here is the animation component code:

```
animations: [
        trigger('rowVisibleState',
        [
            state('true',
                style({
                   height: '40px',
                   opacity: 1,
                   fontSize: '14px',
                   display: 'table-row'
                })),

            transition('0 => 1', [
                animate('500ms ease-in', keyframes([
                    style({ display: 'table-row', offset: 0 }),
                    style({ fontSize: 0, offset: 0 }),
                    style({ height: 0, offset: 0 }),
                    style({ opacity: 0, offset: 0.0 }),
                    style({ height: '40px',fontSize: '14px', display: 'table-row', opacity: 1, offset: 1.0 })
                ]))
            ]),
            state('false',
                style({
                    height: '0px',
                    opacity: 0,
                    display: 'none',
                    fontSize: 0
                })),
            transition('1 => 0', [
                animate('500ms ease-out', keyframes([
                    style({ opacity: 1, offset: 0 }),
                    style({ fontSize: '14px', offset: 0 }),
                  style({ height: '40px', offset: 0 }),
                  style({ fontSize: 0, height: 1, opacity: 0.5, offset: 0.9}),
                  style({ height: '0px', opacity: 1, display: 'none', offset: 1.0 })

                ]))
            ])
            ])
    ]
```